# Failed RPC connection to the node ejabberd

Tags: django, ubuntu, xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

This question asked saveral times.i read all answers but they did not solve my problem.
when i want start service is shows me

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ejabberd start

error msg
Starting jabber server: ejabberd.
```

when i want to register user is shows error

```
sudo ejabberdctl register cp jabber password
```

cp is username
jabber is hostname

```
 error  `Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@cp-HP-EliteBook-8460p': node`
```

**my /etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       cp-HP-EliteBook-8460p

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.10.120 localhost
192.168.10.120 jabber.com jabber
```

**/etc/ejabberd/ejabberd.cfg**

```
%% Admin user
{acl, admin, {user, "cp", "jabber"}}.

%% Hostname
{hosts, ["localhost","ubuntu","jabber"]}.
```

i have every thing but my problem is not solved.Please help me it tookej my two days.

Answer (score 0):

```
`Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@cp-HP-EliteBook-8460p': node`
```

This Error message is coming just because the Ejabberd is not running.
You can check the ejabberd running status by following command:

> sudo ejabberdctl status

If ejabberd is running than a message will display like:

> The node ejabberd@localhost is started with status: started
>
> ejabberd 16.02.26 is running in that node

Otherwise use these commands:

> sudo ejabberdctl start
>
> sudo ejabberdctl status
>
> sudo ejabberdctl register 'username' 'nodename' 'password'

Comment: I have a ejabberd service running but still showing 'Failed RPC connection' error message

Comment: I am getting error with cmd sudo epmd -kill, o/p: 
Killing not allowed - living nodes in database.

Comment: I am getting error 
$ sudo ejabberdctl start
ERROR: The ejabberd node 'ejabberd@localhost' is registered,
       but no related beam process has been found.
Shutdown all other erlang nodes, and call 'epmd -kill'.